# Testing CodenameOne business logic using JUnit

Tags: junit, codenameone

I want to write the business logic of my CodenameOne application using JUnit 5. But when I try to run any unit test in Intellij, the simulator is started with the app instead of the unit tests.

Did anybody figure out how to setup Intellij such that the unit tests can be run without triggering the Ant build?

Answer (score 0):

Codename One has its own unit test API and test recorder, generally you should use that for your testing as it allows you to test everything including the GUI. 
See [this](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/performance-debugging.html) for further details on using the testing framework.

You could probably use JUnit for the pure business logic but I'm not sure what benefit it would provide.

Comment: The _integration test_ support provided by CodenameOne does not allow me to develop my business logic in a TDD style: I want to write many small tests that are completely independent from the CodenameOne runtime, and run very fast. Intellij has amazing support for a TDD workflow, but when I try to run a JUnit test it starts the simulator instead.

Comment: That's because the main method in the project is the method of the simulator. I'm not sure how to workaround this with intellij as I didn't try to use JUnit myself. In NetBeans it would have been easy to workaround via the build.xml.